# Simulating Keyboard Events in Android

Tags: android

I have a project and I am trying to fire Keyboard events. I am using the Instrumentation Class, and it is working perfectly on the emulator, but when I launch it on my device, the call doesn't work, is there any way to make it work?

Also, I searched on the web, and I found some posts about the IWindowManager and the internal APIs, I fully understand the risk of using them, but my project is a research and is not intended to be published, so I don't mind using those APIs in my porject if they can solve my problem, but the problem is that I can't find the JAR that contains these classes.

TLDR : I need a solution that helps me fire keyboard events on my Android device, any ideas are appreciated

Comment: What code are you currently using that works with simulator but not device?

Comment: I am using the Instrumentation class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, there is an easier method, that I found
Using Activity class or WebView class. Both have the same function.
The code looks something like this:

```
webView.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1));
```

Comment: Actually, any class that extends View has this method, as well as dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)....
Might be useful in the future

Answer (score 4):

In instrumentation, there is the api to send keycode:

```
getInstrumentation().sendCharacterSync(int keycode);
```

If you have root access to the device, you can check the code here:

```
https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/source/browse/AndroidScreencastClient/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/client/ClientHandler.java ;
```

to use IWindowManager. The IWindowManager is apart of android system, you can find the class in android.jar, the source code can be downloaded from android official website.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I already found a much easier solution :)