# Android: How to trigger any key pressing event on soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is there any way to press key of Android Soft Keyboard programmatically.

Like: When keyboard will appear, I want to press "J" key through my code not from fingers.

Comment: This action is called "Simulate key press" for future references xD

Comment: @RicardoAlexandre Ok bro, I'll remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First method:

```
IBinder binder = ServiceManager.getService("window"); 
IWindowManager manager = IWindowManager.Stub.asInterface(binder);
manager.injectKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.yourAction, KeyEvent.yourKeyCode),true);
```

You can see more details [here](http://www.pocketmagic.net/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/).
There is another method in this link too.

Second method, using instrumentation:

```
Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
```

And you can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824984/simulating-keyboard-events-in-android) that explains how to use instrumentation and webview to do that.

You don't need the keyboard to do this, you can show it or not.

A list of [keyCodes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tasker/LJhmfxT2mj8%5B1-25%5D) if you want.

This [link](https://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html) will show keyCode for every key that you press, I think it works with the android and linux keyboards, but don't know if the code will be the same using another OS.

Comment: Thanks man! It works perfectly. Can you tell me what is the KeyCode for "?123" on the Android's Soft Keyboard?

Comment: I think is 63, and the constant KEYCODE_SYM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it's not. Constant KEYCODE_SYM will shows an option to change keyboard. I have tried many constants but none of one can able to switch from alphabet keyboard view to numeric with symbols keyboard view. So, I still need that constant which will trigger key press event for "?123".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9292485/1237175. Here they say ServiceManager class is hidden... There is no way i can use it ?

Comment: what about mimicing the ENTER key to be pressed while we're inside another openend activity (of other app) is it possible?

Comment: Note that second method cannot be from the main thread. you must do it from background thread.

Comment: The second method seems to only work for system apps. I got the error `java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission` even after adding the permission to the manifest.