# How to trigger shift-button on Android keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

How can I trigger the "shift-button" on the Android keyboard, so that the next character will be capital?

I set the `InputType` to `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE`, but this doesn't work if the cursor is anywhere in the line.

I have tried [these two methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35753675/7174483). Both don't work. The second one throws a `RuntimeException` ("This method cannot be called from the main application thread"). Maybe because there is no keycode for this button. 
Is there a way to trigger the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

It seems that buttons like shift and alt create meta states that affect pressed buttons. From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html:

> Meta states describe the pressed state of key modifiers such as META_SHIFT_ON or META_ALT_ON.

These meta states can be simulated using `dispatchKeyEvent` like so:

```
dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0,0,KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_L,0,KeyEvent.META_SHIFT_ON));
```

Were an `EditText` in focus this would write "L" into it. But it seems that you cannot only send the shift `KeyEvent` and expect the next character to be uppercase. Perhaps you can come up with some sort of workaround with this.

---

You're using and `EditText`, right? For some reason I can't get

`dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT));`

to work when the EditText is focused while `KeyEvents` for letters and numbers work.

A workaround could be adding a `TextWatcher` to the `EditText`:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "afterTextChanged: "+s.toString());
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            Log.d(TAG, "beforeTextChanged: "+s.toString());
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged: "+s.toString());
        }
    });
```

and checking whether the wanted character of `CharSequence s` is capitalized in `afterTextChanged`. If not, then change it to a capitalized version. This is a bit hacky and doesn't quite answer your question I know but unfortunately I'm not able to comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and no problem i am also not able to comment in other threads. Now to your answer. Yes i am using EditText. Is it then not possible to use that dispatchKeyEvent? Because at the moment i do not do anything. The workaroung is not that thing i would to do. But how do Google it in their GoogleDocs-Writer?